# FlashGet Can't Download from DropDox

Tags: download, dropbox

I'm having problems using [FlashGet](http://www.flashget.com/) to download stuff from [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). I read somewhere that this didn't work. 
Is there absolutely no update, plugin, add-on, hack that could make it work?

And, why doesn't it work? I'd really like to know why. Maybe someone has an idea of what might be causing it.

Details: I copy the URL which, when referenced in Chrome, downloads fine. It's got the Dropbox domain, some sub-folders, a unique sub-folder, and then the file name, plus some php hash (?token_hash=...) information which, when removed, still seems to work fine in Chrome.

Comment: Where did you read that it won't work with Dropbox?

Comment: Sry bout the delay. It's mentioned on this page: http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120301035343AA72iEC